# Can The Performance of CSharpScript Be Improved?

Tags: c#, scripting, code-generation

I have been playing around with `CSharpScript` and it seems to be extremely useful, but the biggest hurdle that I am trying to overcome is how slow the scripts take to execute.  Below is the code that I am using.

One problem area that I can for sure identify (though not the source of the slowness) is the field `_globals`.  I do not want to create a new instance of that class each time an operation is called, but this approach is not thread safe at all.

Any insights into how to improve the performance (if it can be done) and any recommendations for making it thread safe would be much appreciated!

```
public class Globals<TLhs, TRhs>
{
    public TLhs Lhs;

    public TRhs Rhs;
}

public struct Vector3
{
    private static VectorScripts<Vector3> Scripts { get; } = new VectorScripts<Vector3>(new[] {"X", "Y", "Z"});

    public float X;

    public float Y;

    public float Z;

    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public static Vector3 operator *(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) => Scripts.Multiply(lhs, rhs).Result;
}


public class VectorScripts<TVector>
{
    private readonly ScriptRunner<TVector> _multiply;

    private readonly Globals<TVector, TVector> _globals;

    public VectorScripts(IEnumerable<string> components)
    {
        _multiply = CSharpScript.Create<TVector>(Operation("*", components), globalsType: typeof(Globals<TVector, TVector>)).CreateDelegate();
        _globals = new Globals<TVector, TVector>();
    }

    public async Task<TVector> Multiply(TVector lhs, TVector rhs)
    {
        _globals.Lhs = lhs;
        _globals.Rhs = rhs;
        return await _multiply.Invoke(_globals);
    }

    private static string Operation(string operation, IEnumerable<string> components)
    {
        return string.Join("\n", components.Select(component => $"Lhs.{component}{operation}=Rhs.{component};"));
    }
}
```